# Logstash to Elasticsearch adding new data in the fields instead of overwriting the existing data?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, couchdb

My pipeline is like this: CouchDB -> Logstash -> ElasticSearch. Every time I update a field value in CouchDB, the data in Elasticsearch is overwritten. My requirement is that, when data in a field is updated in CouchDB, I want to create a new data in Elasticsearch instead of overwriting the existing one.

My current logstash.conf is like this:

```
input {
    couchdb_changes {
        host => "<ip>"
        port => <port>
        db => "test_database"
        keep_id => false
        keep_revision => true
        initial_sequence => 0
        always_reconnect => true
        #sequence_path => "/usr/share/logstash/config/seqfile"
    }
}

output {
    if([doc][doc_type] == "HR") {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "hrindex_new_1"
            document_id => "%{[doc][_id]}"
            user => elastic
            password => changeme
        }
    }
    if([doc][doc_type] == "SoftwareEngg") {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "softwareenggindex_new"
            document_id => "%{[doc][_id]}"
            user => elastic
            password => changeme
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `document_id` option in your elasticsearch output, what this option does is tell elasticsearch that it should index the document using this value as the document id, which will be a unique id.

```
document_id => "%{[doc][_id]}"
```

So, if in your source document the field `[doc][_id]` has for example the value of `1000`, the `_id` field in the elasticsearch will also have the same value.

When you change something in the source document that has the `[doc][_id]` equals to `1000`, it will replace the document with the `_id` equals to `1000` in elasticsearch because the `_id` is unique.

To achieve what you want, you will need to remove the option `document_id` from your outputs, this way elasticsearch will generate a unique value for the `_id` field of the document.

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "softwareenggindex_new"
    user => elastic
    password => changeme
}
```